# Is it possible to update the dataset using update_post_meta

Tags: php, functions, custom-field

I am trying to create two custom fields for image and text.
I have two inputs in the loop:

```
...
<input type="hidden" name="wt_set['upload_set_img'][]" id="img" value="100" />
<input type="text" name="wt_set['title'][]" value="Text One" />

<input type="hidden" name="wt_set['upload_set_img'][]" id="img1" value="200" />
<input type="text" name="wt_set['title'][]" value="Text Two" />
...
```

The result is this $_POST['wt_set']

```
array(2) {
  ["upload_set_img"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "100"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "200"
  }
  ["title"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "Text One"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "Text Two"
  }
}
```

Then I do this:

```
foreach( $_POST['wt_set'] as $name => $arr_values ){
    foreach( $arr_values as $i => $value){
        update_post_meta( $post_id, $name, $value );
    }
}
```

But I only get one value:

```
  ["upload_set_img"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "100"
  }
  ["title"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "Text One"
  }
```

I need `get_post_meta($post->ID,'upload_set_img');` and `get_post_meta($post->ID,'title');` equaled:

```
["upload_set_img"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "100"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "200"
  }
  ["title"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "Text One"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "Text Two"
  }
```

How do I properly use update_post_meta to get this result?

Comment: it seems like you're missing a part of the puzzle here. If you think about your line:
`update_post_meta( $post_id, $name, $value )` you're only ever going to get 1 value per `$name`. The `$name` is a meta key, so in the 2nd loop you're simply setting the same meta value over and and over again.  There's a 3rd dimension required here. Perhaps instead of `$name`, you use `$name.$i` ?

Comment: Thanks for your willingness to help, I needed to leave one loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need your second `foreach` loop.

```
foreach( $_POST['wt_set'] as $name => $val ){
    update_post_meta( $post_id, $name, $val );
}
```

What's happening is with your second `foreach` is each entry is being processed individually and set as the post meta, so as it's looping through it's running `update_post_meta( $post_id, $name, XXX );` then `update_post_meta( $post_id, $name, XXX );` which overrides the previous one.

Comment: Thank you. I used to do this, but before I did not notice one detail. Now I was more attentive and everything worked as it should.

Comment: If $val contains: `array(2) {[0]=>string(3) "100" [1]=>string(0) ""}`
how to remove empty cell using `delete_post_meta`

Comment: @VladSiy so you just want the array to have non empty values?

Comment: Yes, when updating the post, I want to check if there are empty values and if there are, remove them